# Automatically run a script or a program on wake from standby in Windows 7

Tags: windows, login, automation, standby, wake-up

I have a buggy driver for my Wifi USB dongle.
Every time the computer wakes from standby, the wifi is disabled.

I created a script to restart the device, but I have no idea how to automatically run it when wake from standby.

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a [script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/02/26/how-can-i-monitor-event-log-messages-for-specific-words.aspx) that monitors the event log.  Check the log for what the message is for waking up from standby and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There's a possible solution here: [Run script on resume from standby: post #4](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?s=f70615c393ef56e5e7bba3f63268de1d&p=13094341&postcount=4)

> If you can put your machine into standby mode via a
> shortcut then then all you need to do is get it to run this batch file:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> Rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState
> ping localhost -n 3 > nul
> [your code goes here]
> ```

(`ping` is used because Windows lacks a `sleep` command)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: It's a good solution, but only if you're making the computer go to sleep manually.

Answer (score 1):

This free utility might help : [WakeupOnStandBy](http://www.vista-files.org/programs/dennisbabkin-com/wakeuponstandby.html)

> Can run a file or open a web page at a
>   predetermined time after a wake-up
>   event, during normal operation, or
>   before performing power operation;

(Note: I have no experience with this utility)

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It requires a time to automatically wake up.

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba I can see in the screenshot the option "perform these tasks if computer wakes up earlier", would that do what you're after? There's some more details [here](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/docs.php?what=wosb). It says "If you want to perform scheduled tasks even if computer wakes up earlier than the time specified in item (1), check the appropriate box underneath the date & time control. If checked, this option will first perform all the checked options in item (1), then run a file in the item (2) and trigger additional operations in items (3) and (4)."

Comment: @eis It still requires you do specify a time. I suppose if you set the date to the far future, it will not automatically awake.

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba yeah, since it seems to include a year also, you could set it to 2099 or something